# R survival package - survreg reports singularities when using big intervals

Tags: r

I came across an issue when trying to do an interval regression using the survival package. The goal was merely to estimate the constant using interval censored data.

```
> library(survival)
> y = with(data, Surv(lb, ub, type = "interval2"))
> model_y = survreg(y ~ 1, dist = "gaussian")
> model_y
Call:
survreg(formula = y ~ 1, dist = "gaussian")

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
(Intercept) 
         NA 

Scale= 256178.4 

Loglik(model)= -6186.5   Loglik(intercept only)= -6186.5
n=2556 (132 observations deleted due to missingness)
```

For the intercept NA is reported. Additionally, the remark "(1 not defined because of singularities)" is displayed.

However, once i scale down the bounds of the intervals by a constant factor, proper results are obtained (works for integers > 3):

```
> library(survival)
> y = with(data, Surv(lb/4, ub/4, type = "interval2"))
> model_y = survreg(y ~ 1, dist = "gaussian")
> model_y
Call:
survreg(formula = y ~ 1, dist = "gaussian")

Coefficients:
(Intercept) 
    567.184 

Scale= 64000.89 

Loglik(model)= -6186   Loglik(intercept only)= -6186
n=2556 (132 observations deleted due to missingness)
```

Does anyone have any ideas on why that is?

[Data](https://ufile.io/1nqddyer)

Kind regards

Comment: I might wonder if trying for a gaussian model might run in to problems when the algorithm tries to set up a mean and a standard deviation of 1.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your concern here. What i am trying to do is estimating the intercept with no other coefficients.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what the term "intercept" means in the contexts of survival analysis. Without an an example dataset to work on and discuss there appears to be no takers on your request for "an answer".

Comment: if you would have read the op you would have noticed that the data was attached all along. already from your first response it should have been obvious to me that you have not understood a thing of the op though. nevertheless, problem is already solved anyways. bye

Comment: If you have a solution then the SO rules do encourage you to post it and then after a suitable interval, give yourself an answering check mark. The point about `data` being missing or absent is that unless you have code that creates an object with that name (which I certainly do not see), then running code with `data` as the first argument will find the function named `data` and just throw an error.